# Design C-container with `const` elements?

Tags: c, interface, constants, containers

Should a container interface declare pointers to the contained
elements as `const`?

Task: Design a container in C (Note: this is explicitly about plain C,
*not* about C++, nor C#).  The container is to be fed with pointers to
items, and should return pointers to items.

A somewhat pointless MWE, but the idea extends to useful containers as
well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    void *data;
} container_t;

void put(container_t *c, void *data)
{
    c->data = data;
}

void *get(container_t *c)
{
    return c->data;
}

int main(void)
{
    container_t c;
    int x = 42;
    int *y;

    put(&c, &x);
    y = get(&c);

    printf("value = %d\n", *y);

    return 0;
}
```

So far, so good.

Well, the container should not use the pointers to modify the stored
data.  I'd like to make this clear in the interface, by a small
change:

```
void put(container_t *c, const void *data)
                         ^new
```

Now the compiler asks me to make another change, which I really do
agree with:

```
typedef struct { const void *data; } container_t;
                 ^new
```

Then the compiler asks me to make one more change, which is quite
logical as well:

```
const void *get(container_t *c)
^new
```

And now, the compiler complains about `y` not being `const int *`,
which makes me a bit unhappy.  What is the right way to deal with
this?

- Design the container without `const`?  I see this sometimes in
  library documentation, e.g., Glib
  [https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html#g-queue-push-tail].
  But I'd really like the "safety" `const` provides.
- document that the return value from `get` may need it's `const`
  cast away?  I.e. call as

  ```
  y = (int *)get(&c);
  ```
- I would rather not cast away the `const` **inside** the `get`
  function, as in

  ```
  return (void *)c->data;
  ```

  because I do not know if the caller should actually consider the
  item `const` at all.
  *emphasized text*

Comment: Since `y` is not `const`, you can alter the bytes it is pointing to, that is why the compiler complains. `y = (int *)get(&c);` if you do this, then what is the benefit of the `const`?

Comment: Yes, I know.  I completely understand why the compiler complains.
Benefit of using `const` is twofold: 1: Promise to library *user* that
the container will not modify data.  2: Make compiler warn library
*implementor* about accidentaly modifying data managed by compiler.

Comment: And then why do you want a non-`const` reference to it?

Comment: I am sorry, may be it's because my poor english knowledge, but I don't understand _It just should nott happen inside the container!_, what do you mean with it? Is it that you don't want him/her to have access to the `struct` members?

Comment: There is no way out of this, but either casting the `const` away when returning `data` by the getter or dumping the idea of using `const` at all. I'd go for the latter.

Comment: Please do not call your types `something_t`. The suffix `_t` is reserved by POSIX for its types.

Comment: The `const` qualifier of a function parameter should be interpreted as describing the acceptable type of the corresponding argument.  That is **not** the same thing as what the function will do with the argument, though the two are loosely related.  If your container should store modifiable objects (and provide them back without added type qualification) then your `put()` function should not `const`-qualify its parameters.

Comment: since only pointers are being manipulated, the original data value must still be in existence when the pointer is retrieved.  However, that pointer can be const, as the pointer to the data is const.  However, overall, the container is NOT containing the data, only a pointer to the data, IMO: If the original data is still available, then the container for a pointer to that data is pointless.

Comment: fix my previous comment: Because the library user still wants to modify the data. It just should **not** be modified by the container! –  sorry, hurried typing

Comment: @John Bollinger: Interesting line of thought, I'm su sure I agree, though:  `f(const int *)` an be applied to a wider class of arguments, while `f(int *)` cannot be applied to arguments of type `const int *`.  So omitting `const` would mean that the function requests change to the passed data?

Comment: @stefan no, omitting `const` would mean only that the function does not accept `const` arguments.  It still says nothing about what the function will do with its arguments.  This very question highlights the difference: either container's elements may include `const` data or they may not, and this must be reflected in the signatures of the element getter and setter functions.  That a container that can hold `const` data can *also* hold non-`const` data is irrelevant.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I'm not sure I understand the intention behind two interfaces:  One for `const` data, one for non-`const` data, is that it?  But in that case, I'd also  need two “distinct” types for the container, to make sure that only the corresponding functions (const or non-const) are used with the container.  Further, only the interface with `const` would communicate to the user that the container won't fiddle with the data.

Comment: @stefan, For complete `const`-correctness you need not only separate interfaces but separate data structures.  It's about the nature of the container.  If you draw an element from a container that can hold `const` elements, then it is possible that that element is (intended to be) `const`.  That's what `const`-qualifying the getter function indicates.  Whether any particular element actually *is* `const` is not very relevant, because there is no means within C to convey that information on an element-by-element basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface is making a contract, that is that the object that is passed into it will never be modified through that access. So in essence you would need two container types, or more generally to interfaces, one that supposes that the object is mutable (a `void*` version) and one that supposes that it can be modified (a `void const*` version.

This is a problem that occurs in many places, even in the C library. E.g `memchr` is such an interface that silently does a `const` conversion of the object. This direct treason could be circumvented in modern C with `_Generic`.

Your problem of storing the value and then reproduce it at completely unrelated place in the code can't be avoided. The C and POSIX standards have that problem for `tss_set/tss_get` and `pthread_setspecific/pthread_getspecific`, and solve the problem in an incompatible way. The C variant has `void*` for both, the POSIX variant has `void const*` for setting and `void*` for getting.

Comment: I would not agree that I need two interfaces, see my reply to John Bollinger's comment to my question.  But I choose this answer, because it best describes the problem, and that C's `const` does not provide a solution, well put with “storing the value and then reproduce it at completely unrelated place”

Comment: "*... in the code can't.*" err, cannot what please? "*... be circumvented ...*"?

Comment: @alk, yes, that was the idea. I tried to clarify, now.

Answer (score 2):

A container type is just that - a container. It allows the user to add/remove/access the contained item. What the user does with it is up to the user.

If you still want a pointer to constant then your 2nd approach is what works best. But if a user can cast off const, so can the container's code, as such the promise of not modifying the data is shallow.

Also note that your container stores pointer to void. That it self is a strong indication to the user that the container's code can't do much because it has no idea about the type of data the pointer will be pointing to. Yes, it can still write garbage at that memory location.

Given that the const does not guarantee constantness i.e. the compiler might not place the const data in a read-only memory, the user of the container code can still attempt to use const. Now, it is possible that const data might actually end up in a read-only memory or the user might be providing the container the address from a read-only memory. That is, the user has ensured that no code can modify the constant data. In this case, you do not need to worry about defining a pointer to constant data. If the user has verified that the data cannot be made read-only then s/he can still add stuff like CRC to the data. That way, when s/he grabs the data s/he can verify if the data is reliable or not.

**To summarize**: if you have pointer to void then making it a pointer to const void is kind of pointless. Besides, it is up to the user to protect his/her data. A data structure should only worry about its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`const *` means you can access and modify the data in that address but cannot modify the address you point.

That means if the user want to change your data content, will be able to do. But the address will be remaining the same.

However, everybody is free to set their pointer to some address. You cannot prevent this.

For more information, look at [this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html) link (The C Book - Const and Volatile) chapter 8.4.1.

Comment: `const *` is not a valid type, leaving me uncertain what is meant, but this answer seems headed in the wrong direction.  For example, both `const char *` and `char const *` are (modifiable) pointers unmodifiable `char`.  If you want the *pointer* to be unmodifiable then that's spelled `char * const`.

Comment: you are right. saying const * I guess everybody see what I meant.

Comment: As I said, *I* didn't know what you meant.  I still don't, for that matter.  I might infer that you are talking about unmodifiable pointers if that were in fact relevant to the question, but it is not.

Comment: This is not correct.  In `const *`, the `const` never refers to the `*`.  You mean `* const`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the constness of the y *pointer*, the right way would be: 
`int * const y = get(&c);`

If you want to constify what y *points to*, then, as you mentioned:
`const int * y = get(&c);`

Comment: This is true, but it doesn’t answer the question.